How do I drag up and down a point in QCustomPlot?
How can the round point on the axis graph be selected, so I can print the selected value in the console, and then, how can the point be dragged up or down in QCustomPlot?
void Plot2D_widget::makeplot()
{
    QVector<double> x2 = {.....}; 
    QVector<double> y2 = {.....}; 

    QCPGraph *graph2 = ui->customPlot->addGraph();
    graph2->setData(x2, y2);
    graph2->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssCircle, QPen(Qt::black, 1.5), QBrush(Qt::white), 9));
    graph2->setPen(QPen(QColor(120, 120, 120), 2));

    ui->customPlot->addLayer("abovemain", ui->customPlot->layer("main"), QCustomPlot::limAbove);
    ui->customPlot->addLayer("belowmain", ui->customPlot->layer("main"), QCustomPlot::limBelow);
    
    graph2->setLayer("abovemain");
    
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setLayer("belowmain");
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setLayer("belowmain");
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setBasePen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setBasePen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setSubTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setSubTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelColor(Qt::white);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickLabelColor(Qt::white);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setPen(QPen(QColor(140, 140, 140), 1, Qt::DotLine));
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setPen(QPen(QColor(140, 140, 140), 1, Qt::DotLine));
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setSubGridPen(QPen(QColor(80, 80, 80), 1, Qt::DotLine));
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridPen(QPen(QColor(80, 80, 80), 1, Qt::DotLine));
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(true);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(true);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setZeroLinePen(Qt::NoPen);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setZeroLinePen(Qt::NoPen);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setUpperEnding(QCPLineEnding::esSpikeArrow);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setUpperEnding(QCPLineEnding::esSpikeArrow);

    QLinearGradient plotGradient;
    plotGradient.setStart(0, 0);
    plotGradient.setFinalStop(0, 350);
    plotGradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(80, 80, 80));
    plotGradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(50, 50, 50));
    
    ui->customPlot->setBackground(plotGradient);
    
    QLinearGradient axisRectGradient;
    axisRectGradient.setStart(0, 0);
    axisRectGradient.setFinalStop(0, 350);
    axisRectGradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(80, 80, 80));
    axisRectGradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(30, 30, 30));

    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setBackground(axisRectGradient);
    ui->customPlot->rescaleAxes();
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(*std::min_element(y2.constBegin(), y2.constEnd()), *std::max_element(y2.constBegin(), y2.constEnd()));
    ui->customPlot->replot();
}



What have you tried?  Have you looked at "User Interaction"?
